About OpenStack Wallabies Nova Status Down
In Ubuntu 20.04.5 environment, the OpenStack wallaby is being tested by configuring 3 controller nodes and 2 compute nodes. The configuration is:

Middleware

Percona XtraDB
HAproxy
RabbitMQ
Memcached


Components

Keystone
Glance
Placement
Nova
Cinder (LVM)
Neutron
Horizon



All my issues are that the volume, network, and Flavor will be created normally on the Horizon dashboard after configuration, but eventually the instance creation won't be like the log below.
Block Device Mapping is Invalid: Missing device UUID. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-ae6e7c30-1d54-4029-b92e-6aa41562cf61)

Since then, the Nova and Cinder logs have not had any particular logs. But then I looked at the Nova status using openstack complete service list.
The status of all Nova Scheduler, Nova-conductor, Nova-compute is down, restarting does not change the status, and it is still down. What is the problem?



ID
Binary
Host
Zone
Status
State
Updated At




1
nova-scheduler
cont02
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:41.000000


4
nova-conductor
cont02
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:50.000000


7
nova-scheduler
cont03
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:41.000000


10
nova-conductor
cont03
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:50.000000


13
nova-conductor
cont01
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:50.000000


16
nova-scheduler
cont01
internal
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:41.000000


28
nova-compute
comp02
nova
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:45.000000


31
nova-compute
comp01
nova
enabled
down
2024-04-15T06:14:45.000000



Create a user after Nova is removed and db sync after permission assignment:
openstack user list --domain default
openstack service list
openstack user delete nova
openstack service delete nova
openstack user create --domain default --password cloud1234 nova
openstack role add --project service --user nova admin
openstack service create --name nova --description "OpenStack Compute" compute
openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne compute public http://192.168.20.109:18774/v2.1
openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne compute internal http://192.168.20.109:18774/v2.1
openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne compute admin http://192.168.20.109:18774/v2.1

su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage api_db sync" nova
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 map_cell0" nova
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 create_cell --name=cell1 --verbose" nova
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage db sync" nova
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells" nova
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
systemctl enable nova-api nova-scheduler nova-conductor nova-novncproxy
systemctl restart nova-api nova-scheduler nova-conductor nova-novncproxy


You need to figure out why your nova services are down, maybe wrong configuration?

Thank you.
I made it again
